# How to generate hash_hmac sha1 php?

Tags: php, curl, hmac

I have two problem with hmac

First:

```
$klucz = ""; 
$url = ""; 
$nazwaUsera = "";
$nazwaKlucza = "faktura";

$curlHandle = curl_init($url);

$hashWiadomosci = hmac($klucz, $url .$nazwaUsera.$nazwaKlucza);
$headers = array(
'Accept: application/pdf',
'Content-type: application/pdf; charset = UTF-8',
'Authentication: IAPIS user='.$nazwaUsera.', hmac-
sha1='.$hashWiadomosci
);
```

if is hmac problem is: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function hmac()

Bat if is

```
$klucz = ""; 
$url = ""; 
$nazwaUsera = "";
$nazwaKlucza = "faktura";

$curlHandle = curl_init($url);

$hashWiadomosci = hash_hmac($klucz, $url, $nazwaUsera.$nazwaKlucza);
$headers = array(
'Accept: application/pdf',
'Content-type: application/pdf; charset = UTF-8',
'Authentication: IAPIS user='.$nazwaUsera.', hmac-
sha1='.$hashWiadomosci
);
```

problem is: Warning: hash_hmac(): Unknown hashing algorithm: EC8A18CEC9D1F1B2

how solved this?

Comment: Seems like you are using the wrong syntax for the hash. It tries to interpret your input `EC8A18CEC9D1F1B2` as the name/parameter of a hash function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
hashWiadomosci = hash_hmac('sha256', $klucz . $url, $nazwaUsera.$nazwaKlucza);
```

First parameter must be the hash algorithm you need to be used (you can call [`hash_algos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) to inspect supported algorithms in your platform. I.E. md5", "sha256", "haval160,4".

Comment: Now is: {
  "response" : {
    "Kod" : 403,
    "Info" : "Wrong hash send meesages."
  }
}

Comment: Try with `sha1` instead of `sha256`. And read service's documentation.